# Is Estonian Temporary Residence Permit a 'common format residence permit'?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, permits, estonia

I would like to know if the Estonian Temporary Residence Permit is a valid common format residence permit issued by an EEA.

Also does it allow me to transit in the UK without having to apply for a UK Transit Visa?

Attached: Temporary Residence Permit[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a common format residence permit, issued by Estonia (EST-HO-05004) since 2018.

[image]

---

Since 2020 with a new design (EST-HO-07001):

[image]

---

> Also does it allow me to transit in the UK without having to apply for a UK Transit Visa?

Yes, if then first 3 conditions listed below are fulfilled

- the fourth condition is fulfilled

> [You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit - Check if you need a UK visa - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/afghanistan/transit/somewhere_else/yes)
>
> **Transiting without a visa**.
> You may be eligible to transit without a visa if:
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> One of the following must also apply:.
> ...
>
> - you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland.
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [PRADO - 2020 EST-HO-07001](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/EST-HO-07001/index.html)
- [PRADO - 2018 EST-HO-05004](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/EST-HO-05004/index.html)
- [ANNEX 22 LIST OF RESIDENCE PERMITS ISSUED BY MEMBER STATES](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/document/download/94241914-26f6-464d-be28-c601d8ded4d5_en) (PDF, page 24):

> Documents in the uniform format which are issued to third country nationals proving that they hold a residence permit or have the right of residence, issued as of 1 January 2011.
> The document number is composed of 2 letters and seven digits. The first letter in the number of the residence permit refers to the type of residence permit or right of residence:.
>
> - B – third-country national;
> - P – long-term resident;
> - F – residence card of a family member of an EU citizen;
>
> The title of the document, 'ELAMISLUBA', is found in the middle of the upper edge of the front of the residence permit card, with the English title, 'Residence permit', located on the bottom edge.